mixing water-based polyurethane with isopropanol
As far as I know, the (oil-based) wipe-on polyurethane (PU) is just PU mixed with mineral spirits. The latter,being volatile, fastens drying time.
I am trying to find an alternative solution for water-based PU (WBPU). In the first place, I am using WBPU and not OBPU because I want to dye the PU, and the dye that I have is hydrophilic i.e. it dissolves in water (and obviously not in oil).
Given that

water mixes with isopropanol
isopropanol is volatile

I thought about mixing WBPU, isopropanol and the dye, so that I would have a tinted WBPU that evaporates faster than WBPU only.
I have looked online and found a bunch of 'recipes' on how to make my own (oil-based) wipe on PU. Less information I found about the same for WBPU, so I am wondering if anyone has tried something similar, and whether my idea is set to fail or shall it work?

There's a lot to unpack here, but it's very much not as simple as this, any part of it in fact (sorry). Firstly, and rather confusingly, PU is actually a minor component of both oil-based poly and the waterbased versions. It's natural to think polyurethane is the major constituent given the naming convention, but that's not the case; the full name for the oil-based version helps clarify this, it's more accurately called uralkyd varnish — urethane-modified alkyd varnish.


As far as I know, the (oil-based) wipe-on polyurethane (PU) is just PU mixed with mineral spirits. The latter,being volatile, fastens drying time.

Wipe-on poly is oil-based poly thinned down, yes. This is why it's so easy to replicate at home, you just dilute it by however much you want and bingo, you're there :-)
It 'dries' faster because so much less of the starting varnish — the part that remains on the wood — is applied. Naturally, this is specially if following the usual application method where most/all excess is wiped away.

I am trying to find an alternative solution for water-based PU (WBPU). In the first place, I am using WBPU and not OBPU because I want to dye the PU, and the dye that I have is hydrophilic i.e. it dissolves in water (and obviously not in oil).
...
I thought about mixing WBPU, isopropanol and the dye, so that I would have a tinted WBPU that evaporates faster than WBPU only.

OK, for starters, waterbased finishes already tend to dry fast enough that it's a bit of an issue for some users, especially on an absorbent substrate like wood (although this effect lessens with further coats).
And since it's wiping varnish specifically that you want to replicate you absolutely don't want to speed the drying any further!
The usual technique for wiping varnish relies heavily on the fact that it's a slow-drying finish (initial drying, unrelated to curing  where it becomes ready to apply the next coat) and if you sped the drying time up by as little as 30-40% it could already pose a problem. Waterbased finishes dry something like 400% faster already!
In addition to that, quite a number of waterbased finishes do not play well with alcohol in any significant quantity. A waterbased finish such as this is variously called an emulsion or suspension and the latter is more accurate — the water surrounds microscopic droplets of the finish, which are suspended in the water. Alcohol can disrupt this suspension in some finishes, particularly if added in quantity; small amounts (very small) are often tolerated. Where the alcohol does cause a problem the effect is catastrophic so there'd be no doubt if it occurred, and it's generally immediate too. The finish might become gooey/stringy, or 'curdle'  to a consistency similar to cottage cheese.

I have looked online and found a bunch of 'recipes' on how to make my own (oil-based) wipe on PU. Less information I found about the same for WBPU, so I am wondering if anyone has tried something similar, and whether my idea is set to fail or shall it work?

There are good reasons for this and that it's not generally considered doable to convert waterbased finishes to a wipe-on version. It is conceivable, after all there are commercial versions (but worth noting, not many), but simply adding more water doesn't really do it.
My strongest advice to get to approximately where you want to be is:

go the route of tinting or otherwise colouring oil-based poly and then diluting it as needed to convert it to wiping-varnish.
buy a commercial coloured poly and thin that the same way.

It's usually the case that oil-based poly is fundamentally a better finish than waterbased poly, so in addition to the much easier workability you would end up with a more durable and resistant end result anyway.

the issue with OBPU is that I could not find a dye that dissolves in it, so I bought WBPU, not knowing that, in general, I can expect a better finish with the former

A good waterbased finish is totally fine to use. With a better-than-average one the level of protection is perfectly adequate for many, perhaps even most, projects. The real issue in the context of the Q is simply the conversion to anything remotely like wiping varnish; sure you can get close, but if you want wiping varnish with all its inherent upsides then oil-based is the way to go. There's a trick for getting alcohol-soluble dyes into oil, but there are dyes for oil-based finishes, see more in this Pop Woodworking article, here.

So back to your WB finish, you can of course colour this in numerous ways including of course using a standard woodworking dye like TransTint; be cautious adding this by the way, in case you don't know it's very potent stuff — 2 large drops in a given volume can much too much. Waterbased finishes, decent ones, are known to lay down well if applied as directed, with care taken not to rework areas or create dry edges. So there's no reason not to use this only in a different way to how you originally envisaged. I do want to add though, directly colouring the wood is generally a superior choice.

I've always put the dye under the water based poly but, with something in between.  After the dye (in my case Atri  dyes), I apply a spray coat of shellac then start my multi-coat water based poly application.  When applying the dye I have control which means I could wet wipe it off and go again - I've not had to do that yet but I know I could if needed.  Once anything else contacts that dye, you're stuck with it short of totally sanding it off.  If you really feel the need to bring isopropanol into the mix, why not start with an alcohol based dye.
By the way, shellac is alcohol based.

I use the same technique for water based lacquer.  It's more important to put that barrier coat between dye and finish on water based lacquer because water based lacquer to some extent will dissolve previous water based lacquer.  Poly doesn't dissolve poly thus the need to sand between coats.

so if I understand correctly, the shellac is to avoid that the downstream coats of (colourless) WBPU will dissolve the tinted WBPU previously applied

Not only water based poly but water itself.  If any of that dye gets to the surface and if that surface gets damp, there is a possibility a hint of that dye could be present.  What if that damp surface is fiber, as in cloth or carpet.
